# Problem while using the Loader Component in Flash CS4

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, external, loader

Please I am facing a problem using the Loader component in Flash CS4. Here are the details:

---

**The Source Code:**

```
var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();    
mcLoader.loadClip("Gallery.swf",myLoader);
```

---

**Notes:**

1. "Gallery.swf" is the name of my file that i need to load.
2. "myLoader" is the name of the loader component that i am using.
3. The dimensions of my external swf stage ("Gallery.swf") are the same the dimensions of ("myLoader") component.

---

**The Problems:**

1. The File is getting loaded with wrong scaled font and size of the components.
2. All the Actionscript of the loaded file is not working at all. (Note that the file is working perfectly by its own just when being loaded into another project, it's getting messed up).

---

Any ideas or suggestions are highly appreciated. Please let me know if more details are needed.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

### Actionscript 3 Loading external swf

```
var req : URLRequest = new URLRequest("Gallery.swf");
var loader : Loader = new Loader( );
loader.load(req);
addChild(loader);
```

If you want to scale or set position you can refer to the existing loader component (you don't have to use *myLoader* ).

```
loader.scaleX = 0.5;
loader.scaleY = 0.5;
loader.x = 100;
loader.y = 100;
```

Is essential to use event listener to detect when loading is complete.

```
var req : URLRequest = new URLRequest("Test2.swf");
var loader : Loader = new Loader( );
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , swfLoaded);
loader.load(req);

function swfLoaded( ev: Event ):void
{
  addChild(loader); 
}
```

If you want to use a method or reference to an object of your child swf,typecast you loaders content.

```
function swfLoaded( ev: Event ):void
{
  var swf : MovieClip = MovieClip(loader.content);
  swf.play();   
}
```

That way you reference to your child timeline.
If you encounter problem try typecast to Object.

### **Swf files must use the same Actionscipt version in order to work!**